# How to get the value of "this" inside of MagnificPopup?

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I have the following code:

```
jQuery('.rel-vid a').magnificPopup({
    type:'inline'
});
```

which opens a popup. I have a movie that is in the popup that I want to dynamically change given the link clicked on. The only problem is that I need to know the value of "this" but I can't clearly make out how I'm supposed to access that with this plugin. I can provide any necessary details.

Edit: 
http://jsfiddle.net/pe8Vm/5/

This is just the plugin and calling it. Providing for your convenience.

Comment: Couldn't you load everything into a variable and print it out to the console? [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atomicpages/CSuNT/)

Comment: _I can provide any necessary details_. Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: Ok I provided a fiddle of MagnificPopup. It isn't my exact setup but I think it's irrelevant: all I want is the value of "this" is (for instance, if I was binding a jQuery click event, the value of "this" would be the exact element I was clicking. I want the same exact situation here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I believe I finally understood what you wanted.

Inside an event, you can call:

```
this.ev // This gets the jQuery-wrapped caller object.
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/EZSlaver/zdNek/)

Comment: We can get the javascript node with this method, but how can we retrieve the JQuery object (ie : the <a/> object, for instance) ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comment. My mistake.